# How to record changes made in vuetify Datatables?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In the given link we can edit some columnn How to record/console those changes so that we can pass that changed data to other component                                                                                     [Check link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKJgNg?&editors=101)

```
<v-edit-dialogue> is used
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline editing is achieved by using first the scoped slot of the [`<v-data-table />`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) component. Within the scoped slot, you use [`<v-edit-dialog />`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/blob/master/examples/data-tables/editdialog.vue#L8) component. And within the input slot of the edit dialog component, you use the [`<v-text-field />`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields) component.

So, just bind to the input or change event of the text field component, and you have the hook you are looking for.

```
<v-data-table>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>
            <v-edit-dialog> 
                {{ props.item.name }}
                <v-text-field
                    slot="input"
                    v-model="props.item.name"
                    @input="onEditValueChanged" <--------- 
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-edit-dialog>
        </td>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```